# wordpress Get user count from other site

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I have a question about the possibility of a user count from another site.
The company I work at has an account for every employee on our main-site WordPress, which we display on the our-people page, making it dynamic.

The company I work at also has a website for a specific product with a employee-counter, only it is static.

Is it possible to get the user count from our main website and display it on our product-website, thus making it dynamic?

EDIT: Think it might be possible with a AJAX request, but don't know how...

@misorude The other site is also WordPress. With static I only meant the employee number is static, and needs to be dynamic.
The sites are hosted at the same provider, but on different packets.

EDIT 2:
The new problem is basically this: How do I let only the client side interact with those API calls? I don't want those API calls to be public and be called by simply entering the link on browser.

edit 3:

```
function getUserAmount() {
    $users = get_users();
   
    if ( empty( $users ) ) {
      return 'There aren\'t any users to display.';
    }
    return count($users);
}

/* Preparing to serve an API request */
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v2', '/wp/colleagues', 
        array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'getUserAmount',
        )
    );
} );
```

How can I make it public? I can only get the data if i'm logged in.

Comment: So this other site is not a WordPress, but just something static? Are they hosted on the same server, or totally different machines? Depending on specifics, it could either be done by embedding the wp-load.php of WordPress, so that WP functionality can be used, or by querying the relevant database table directly.

Comment: You can make an AJAX request to get a list of users pretty easily. URL is just `{yourWordpressDomain}/wp-json/wp/v2/users`.

Comment: @maiorano84 I have a Disable REST API plug-in installed. How do I make sure the other site gets access? Is that possible

Comment: The new problem is basically this: How do I let only the client side interact with those API calls? I don't want those API calls to be public and be called by simply entering the link on browser.

Comment: Depends on how much work you want to do on the other website. Can you do what you want with that specific plugin installed out of the box? Not easily. You would either have to disable the plugin and roll your own filters to highjack unauthenticated requests (a naive check would be to allow only requests from the product website). Otherwise, you could just [roll your own endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) that displays just the user count, and other meta information you might need.

Comment: @maiorano84 See my new edit. This only works if i'm loggedin

Comment: @JurreN That's a plugin issue. Check your plugin's settings. You may have to enable your endpoint on its settings page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED IT:
I wanted to display the user count so I implemented this code:

```
/* Function custom API ROUTE user count*/
function getUserAmount() {
    $users = get_users(); // Get all wordpress users

    if ( empty( $users ) ) { // If there aren't any users display an error
      return 'There aren\'t any users to display.';
    }
    return count($users); // Return amount of users
}
/* Preparing to serve an API request */
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( '/wp/v2', '/users', 
        array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'getUserAmount',
        )
    );
} );
```

Next I opened the /wp-json/wp/v2/users in the Disable REST API plug-in.

At first I tried using my self-made url: /wp-json/api/wp/colleagues/, but this didn't work, because I couldn't open it in the plug-in, so it was blocked.

Just using a regular link (/wp-json/wp/v2/users) and returning `count()` instead of it's normal value, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

There is a `X-WP-Total` property in your `Headers` response when you request to the `<YOUR_DOMAIN>/wp-json/wp/v2/users` that says how many users registered in your website.

[image]